# Not unique table/alias: 'user' error in MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

SO this is my query:

```
 SELECT user_items.userid, users.username FROM user_items, users
 LEFT JOIN users ON user_items.userid = users.username
```

And this is how my database looks:

[image: Database]

I get the error: Not unique table/alias: 'user'
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're referencing the `users` table twice.  Why?

Comment: `FROM user_items, users
 LEFT JOIN users` Drop the old ansi comma join method it is over 25 year old use proper JOIN syntax.. Besides its **NOT** adviced to **never** mix ansi JOIN syntax with modern JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - your've used users table twice with explicit and implicit join

```
SELECT user_items.userid, users.username FROM user_items
LEFT JOIN users ON user_items.userid = users.username
```

Comment: This answer would be complete with an explanation of carthesian join and left join